# World of Warcraft account - From Free Edition to Paid

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I played the free edition and got to level 20. I would like to continue playing my account with same heroes after I convert to a paid account. It is possible?

Comment: Paid and free aren't separate accounts.  Instead, you just can't log in on characters that are level 21+ when you don't have an active subscription; there are some other chat and trade restrictions as well.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can keep playing World of Warcraft with your existing trial characters after paying for a subscription. You won't lose any progress. Just note that if you ever decide to not renew your sub, once it expires you won't be able to play any of your characters that are level 21 or higher.

Comment: Also note that if you renew your subscription after being inactive for some time, your characters will again be available to you.